# Do I need to delete files downloaded over http with picasso?

Tags: android, picasso

I am making an app that acts somewhat like a gallery, but the images are going to be stored on a Firebase database. I am using Picasso to make this easier. Each image can be quite large in size, and there are a lot of them.

I am currently using fragments on a viewpager to display the images, and also a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I know the adapter gets rid of the fragments, but I was wondering whether I had to delete the images I downloaded from device storage, and if so how. (I don't know exactly how Picasso works)

I'm sorry if this is a stupid/obvious question but I'm paranoid about clogging up memory and I've looked around the internet to no avail.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you don't need the image in offline mode of your app then storing it in the device storage is not the way. Picasso will not delete it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`Picasso.with(this)
                .load(url)
                .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
                .into(imageView);`

or you can do something like this

`mPicasso.with(appContext).invalidate(url);`